# Convert varchar to date (german and english date convertion aswell)

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, type-conversion

I have the table "good_thru" and the entries are in German and have the following Format "Jan 06".

I tried to replace every german Month with the english ones and then use the following Code:

```
ALTER TABLE customer
ALTER COLUMN good_thru type date USING to_date(good_thru, 'Mon DD');
```

The result was kind of corrupt to be honest:

```
"0001-09-24 BC"
"0001-06-23 BC"
"0001-11-22 BC"
"0001-01-24 BC"
"0001-10-23 BC"
"0001-03-25 BC"
"0001-09-22 BC"
"0001-07-25 BC"
"0001-02-25 BC"
"0001-03-23 BC"
"0001-09-22 BC"
"0001-07-22 BC"
"0001-10-24 BC"
"0001-12-22 BC"
```

Can someone helping me convert these entries from varchat into date?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to need a year.  Something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE customer
    ALTER COLUMN good_thru type date USING to_date('2002 ' || good_thru, 'YYYY Mon DD');
```